How to assign a value to observations depending on the rate at which the value appears in the population (R)
I have a dataframe (df) with a column "problem" which details the medical conditions which people present to the emergency department with (e.g. "sprain", "cut", "infection").
However, some people left before they could be seen - in this case their problem is labelled "left before being seen".
I want to change my dataframe to impute what the problem each of these "left before being seen" people was attending A&E for.
I have each problems' proportion in the population:
sprain = 0.3
cut = 0.5
infection = 0.2.

How do I assign "sprain", "cut" and "infection" randomly to observations in my dataframe for which "problem" = "left before being seen", based on the rate at which these problems appear in the population? This would be in a new column called "imputed_problem" so I don't lose the data on which people left before being seen.
Note: this data is the whole population, not a sample.

You can use sample to randomly assign the index values to a vector of those three problems with the given counts that have your desired proportions.
n.left <- sum(df$problem=="left before being seen")

n.sprain <- round(n.left * 0.3)
n.cut <- round(n.left * 0.5)
n.infection <- n.left - (n.sprain + n.cut)

df$imputed_problem[df$problem=="left before being seen"] <- c(
  rep('sprain', n.sprain),
  rep('cut', n.cut), 
  rep('infection', n.infection))[sample(1:n.left)]

Check
prop.table(table(df$imputed_problem))

      cut infection    sprain 
      0.5       0.2       0.3


Data:
df <- structure(list(problem = c("cut", "infection", "cut", "sprain", 
"cut", "cut", "sprain", "cut", "cut", "infection", "cut", "sprain", 
"sprain", "sprain", "infection", "sprain", "cut", "sprain", "infection", 
"sprain", "cut", "infection", "cut", "infection", "infection", 
"cut", "cut", "sprain", "infection", "sprain", "infection", "infection", 
"infection", "cut", "cut", "sprain", "infection", "sprain", "sprain", 
"cut", "infection", "sprain", "infection", "infection", "cut", 
"cut", "cut", "cut", "infection", "cut", "cut", "cut", "cut", 
"infection", "cut", "cut", "cut", "sprain", "sprain", "infection", 
"infection", "sprain", "sprain", "infection", "sprain", "sprain", 
"infection", "infection", "cut", "cut", "sprain", "cut", "infection", 
"infection", "cut", "cut", "cut", "cut", "cut", "infection", 
"cut", "sprain", "cut", "infection", "sprain", "sprain", "sprain", 
"cut", "cut", "cut", "infection", "cut", "sprain", "cut", "sprain", 
"cut", "sprain", "cut", "infection", "cut", "sprain", "cut", 
"cut", "cut", "cut", "cut", "cut", "cut", "sprain", "sprain", 
"sprain", "cut", "cut", "cut", "cut", "sprain", "sprain", "sprain", 
"sprain", "cut", "infection", "sprain", "infection", "sprain", 
"infection", "infection", "cut", "infection", "sprain", "cut", 
"infection", "infection", "infection", "sprain", "cut", "sprain", 
"cut", "sprain", "cut", "infection", "infection", "infection", 
"cut", "sprain", "infection", "sprain", "sprain", "cut", "sprain", 
"cut", "cut", "sprain", "sprain", "sprain", "cut", "cut", "cut", 
"cut", "cut", "sprain", "cut", "cut", "cut", "cut", "sprain", 
"sprain", "infection", "sprain", "cut", "cut", "cut", "sprain", 
"sprain", "cut", "cut", "cut", "infection", "sprain", "cut", 
"infection", "cut", "cut", "infection", "sprain", "sprain", "cut", 
"cut", "sprain", "cut", "sprain", "infection", "cut", "cut", 
"cut", "sprain", "cut", "cut", "cut", "infection", "cut", "cut", 
"infection", "cut", "sprain", "sprain", "infection", "sprain", 
"cut", "cut", "sprain", "infection", "infection", "sprain", "sprain", 
"cut", "sprain", "cut", "infection", "cut", "infection", "infection", 
"cut", "cut", "cut", "cut", "sprain", "cut", "infection", "cut", 
"cut", "sprain", "cut", "cut", "sprain", "cut", "cut", "cut", 
"infection", "cut", "sprain", "cut", "infection", "sprain", "sprain", 
"sprain", "cut", "cut", "sprain", "sprain", "cut", "cut", "sprain", 
"sprain", "cut", "infection", "sprain", "cut", "cut", "cut", 
"cut", "cut", "infection", "sprain", "sprain", "infection", "cut", 
"cut", "sprain", "cut", "sprain", "cut", "cut", "cut", "sprain", 
"sprain", "infection", "cut", "sprain", "cut", "sprain", "cut", 
"infection", "cut", "sprain", "cut", "cut", "infection", "infection", 
"cut", "cut", "sprain", "cut", "infection", "infection", "infection", 
"cut", "cut", "infection", "cut", "sprain", "sprain", "cut", 
"cut", "cut", "sprain", "infection", "cut", "cut", "cut", "cut", 
"cut", "sprain", "cut", "cut", "sprain", "cut", "infection", 
"cut", "sprain", "cut", "sprain", "infection", "sprain", "cut", 
"infection", "cut", "sprain", "infection", "sprain", "sprain", 
"cut", "infection", "sprain", "cut", "cut", "sprain", "sprain", 
"infection", "sprain", "cut", "sprain", "cut", "sprain", "cut", 
"cut", "infection", "cut", "cut", "cut", "sprain", "cut", "infection", 
"cut", "infection", "cut", "cut", "sprain", "infection", "infection", 
"cut", "cut", "sprain", "cut", "cut", "sprain", "infection", 
"cut", "cut", "infection", "sprain", "cut", "sprain", "cut", 
"cut", "cut", "sprain", "infection", "cut", "cut", "infection", 
"cut", "cut", "cut", "cut", "cut", "sprain", "sprain", "sprain", 
"infection", "cut", "sprain", "sprain", "sprain", "cut", "cut", 
"sprain", "cut", "cut", "cut", "cut", "cut", "cut", "sprain", 
"cut", "cut", "infection", "infection", "sprain", "infection", 
"cut", "infection", "cut", "cut", "cut", "sprain", "cut", "cut", 
"sprain", "sprain", "infection", "sprain", "cut", "cut", "sprain", 
"cut", "cut", "cut", "cut", "cut", "sprain", "infection", "infection", 
"sprain", "cut", "cut", "sprain", "infection", "sprain", "sprain", 
"cut", "cut", "cut", "cut", "cut", "sprain", "cut", "infection", 
"sprain", "sprain", "cut", "sprain", "cut", "cut", "sprain", 
"cut", "sprain", "cut", "cut", "cut", "sprain", "sprain", "cut", 
"sprain", "cut", "infection", "cut", "cut", "cut", "cut", "sprain", 
"cut", "cut", "cut", "cut", "sprain", "cut", "cut", "infection", 
"infection", "cut", "cut", "cut", "infection", "cut", "sprain", 
"cut", "cut", "sprain", "infection", "cut", "sprain", "sprain", 
"cut", "sprain", "infection", "infection", "cut", "cut", "cut", 
"sprain", "left before being seen", "left before being seen", 
"left before being seen", "left before being seen", "left before being seen", 
"left before being seen", "left before being seen", "left before being seen", 
"left before being seen", "left before being seen", "left before being seen", 
"left before being seen", "left before being seen", "left before being seen", 
"left before being seen", "left before being seen", "left before being seen", 
"left before being seen", "left before being seen", "left before being seen", 
"left before being seen", "left before being seen", "left before being seen", 
"left before being seen", "left before being seen", "left before being seen", 
"left before being seen", "left before being seen", "left before being seen", 
"left before being seen", "left before being seen", "left before being seen", 
"left before being seen", "left before being seen", "left before being seen", 
"left before being seen", "left before being seen", "left before being seen", 
"left before being seen", "left before being seen", "left before being seen", 
"left before being seen", "left before being seen", "left before being seen", 
"left before being seen", "left before being seen", "left before being seen", 
"left before being seen", "left before being seen", "left before being seen"
)), row.names = c(NA, -550L), class = "data.frame")

